# Nested If statement with Conditional "and" in SQL

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

I have this line of code

```cs
string sqlQuery = "SELECT studentid,StudentName,age,contact FROM tblStudent2 ";

if (txtStudentName.Text != "" && txtStudentId.Text != "" && txtAge.Text != "" && txtContact.Text != "")
{
    sqlQuery += " Where ";

    if (txtStudentName.Text != "")
    {
        sqlQuery += "studentId = '" + txtStudentName.Text + "'";
    }
    sqlQuery += " and ";

    if (txtStudentId.Text != "")
    {
        sqlQuery += "studentId = '" + txtStudentId.Text + "'";
    }
    sqlQuery += " and ";

    if (txtAge.Text != "")
    {
        sqlQuery += "age ='" + txtAge.Text + "'";
    }

    sqlQuery += " and ";

    if (txtContact.Text != "")
    {
        sqlQuery += " FROM tblStudent2 Where contact ='" + txtContact.Text + "'";
    }
}
```

My question goal is to select from the table (**tblStudent2**) . With this SQL statement

> "SELECT studentid,StudentName,age,contact FROM tblStudent2 " + "and (TableColumns) and (TableColumns)""

But the goal is to add the "and" in between the nested IF parameters, if i were to add it into the if statement the resulting sqlQuery will result with an "and" as the last word of the sentence if i append the "and" word.

Comment: Concatenating SQL is a recipe for disaster. Don't do it. Use parameterized queries, lest ye fall victim to [Little Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/). There's tons of information about it on Stack Overfow and Oracle's web site.

Comment: I have a seperate function to parse this query in. My seperate function has been tested and it's resilient to sql injections i guess. I understand the danger of sql injection. Thank you for warning me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's better to append 'AND' at the end of each statement placed in ***if*** condition and remove the last one like below:

```
string sqlQuery = "SELECT studentid,StudentName,age,contact FROM tblStudent2";
bool flag = false;
if (txtStudentName.Text != "")
    {
        sqlQuery += "StudentName = '" + txtStudentName.Text + "' and ";
        flag = true;
    }
if (txtStudentId.Text != "")
    {
        sqlQuery += "studentId = '" + txtStudentId.Text + "' and ";
        flag = true;
    }
if (txtAge.Text != "")
    {
        sqlQuery += "age ='" + txtAge.Text + "' and ";
        flag  = true;
    }
if (txtContact.Text != "")
    {
        sqlQuery += "contact ='" + txtContact.Text + "' and ";
        flag = true;
    }
if (flag == true){
    sqlQuery += " WHERE " + sqlQuery.Substring(0, myString.Length-5);
}
```

Comment: Thanks i think this code will work perfectly. 

I was scratching my head getting it to work. I learned some new commands especially the substring it helps alot with editing the code.

Comment: Or start with `WHERE 1=1` and then append each condition where needed: `+ " AND column=value"`

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest writing this logic without the boolean:

```
string sqlQuery = "SELECT studentid,StudentName,age,contact FROM tblStudent2";
string sqlWhere = ""
if (txtStudentName.Text != "")
    {
        sqlWhere += "StudentName = '" + txtStudentName.Text + "' and ";
    }
if (txtStudentId.Text != "")
    {
        sqlWhere += "studentId = '" + txtStudentId.Text + "' and ";
    }
if (txtAge.Text != "")
    {
        sqlWhere += "age ='" + txtAge.Text + "' and ";
    }
if (txtContact.Text != "")
    {
        sqlWhere += "contact ='" + txtContact.Text + "' and ";
    }
if (sqlWhere != "") {
    sqlQuery += " WHERE " + sqlWhere.Substring(0, myString.Length-5);
}
```

That said, your code has a MAJOR problem.  You are munging the query string with user-input values -- both due to SQL injection and due to unexpected (and hard to debug) syntax errors.  This is *very* dangerous.  You should be parameterizing the query, so it looks more like:

```
if (txtStudentName.Text != "")
    {
        sqlWhere += "StudentName = @StudentName and "
    }
```

(and so on).

Then pass the parameters into the query when you execute it.